# The entity type not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to log changes in costumer details table. For that I am using EF4

```
using (realstateEntities context = new realstateEntities())
{
    //Here the model is built**
    cadClientes cliente = new cadClientes();
    cliente.Nome = model.nome;
    ...
    cliente.observacao = model.observacao;

    //Here I am adding the model and saving the changes**
    context.cadClientes.Add(cliente);
    context.SaveChanges();                                

    //Now I am trying to log that operation** (Error is in following line)
     paramsOriginais = LogsController.PrintProperties("cadClientes", context.Entry(context.cadClientes).GetDatabaseValues());

}
```

**and I get this error:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type DbSet`1 is not part
>   of the model for the current context.\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Entry[TEntity](TEntity entity)\r\n   at
>   realstate.Controllers.CadastrosController.clienteAdd(ClientesModel
>   model, FormCollection form) in c:\Users\guilherme\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2012\Projects\realstate\realstate\Controllers\CadastrosController.cs:line
>   303"

I wrote my code based in this example from microsoft website:

```
using (var context = new UnicornsContext())
{
    var unicorn = context.Unicorns.Find(1);

    // Make a modification to Name in the tracked entity
    unicorn.Name = "Franky";

    // Make a modification to Name in the database
    context.Database.SqlCommand("update Unicorns set Name = 'Squeaky' where Id = 1");

    // Print out current, original, and database values
    Console.WriteLine("Current values:");
    PrintValues(context.Entry(unicorn).CurrentValues);

    Console.WriteLine("\nOriginal values:");
    PrintValues(context.Entry(unicorn).OriginalValues);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDatabase values:");
    PrintValues(context.Entry(unicorn).GetDatabaseValues());
}
```

Could u please help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is caused by `context.Entry(context.cadClientes)`.

`cadClientes` is a `DbSet` of `cadCliente` entities. The entity - `cadCliente` - is part of the model, the `DbSet` isn't. I think what you intended to do is

```
context.Entry(cliente)
```

This would work and it would log the added entity.